# how to send data to many headers in php ? i tried but it didn't work . it's only redirecting the last header

Tags: php, apache, web

I send two headers as you see down and i want to take the same id in the next two pages but it couldn't work this way

```
        if($username == $dbname && $password == $dbpass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id']=$dbid;



        //Redirect to member
        header("Location: updatename.php");
        header("Location: Viewdata.php");

    }
}   else{
    echo ' Invalid username or password.';
    }
```

Comment: `if(condition){ send one header, not two } else{ send the other one }` and be sure to add `exit;` after each  *seperate* header.

Comment: [Does the manual say you can use 2 headers?...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). No, so there's your answer. PHP's done its job and has run the "last" directive.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i want to use the both headers at same time because i want to keep the id logged in into the second page in case requested to perform some queries according to same id.

Comment: @AdelHawa since you have the id stored in a session you can call it no matter what page you are on

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 headers -- once PHP has redirected with a header call, you've moved to a different PHP script, and will not return to the one you called the new page from. Therefore, assuming your first script simply updates things on the back end and isn't used to render HTML, instead of using the `header()` call twice, `include` the first, then redirect to the second:

```
    if($username == $dbname && $password == $dbpass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id']=$dbid;



        //Include updatename.php, then redirect
        include "updatename.php";
        header("Location: Viewdata.php");

    }
}   else{
    echo ' Invalid username or password.';
    }
```

If, on the other hand, you need to display output from both, you could `include` both:

```
    if($username == $dbname && $password == $dbpass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id']=$dbid;



        //Include both updatename.php and Viewdata.php
        include "updatename.php";
        include "Viewdata.php";

    }
}   else{
    echo ' Invalid username or password.';
    }
```

Also: I'm assuming there's an outer `if` statement before this one that was left out of your posted code. If this isn't the case, you've closed this `if` statement twice -- which will cause an error.

Comment: `include "updatename.php";` careful that doesn't hold any content that is considered as ouput.